# Create and export .apk file using Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I've created an Android app, I want to export it as .apk file so that I can share it with others, can anyone tell me how to create and share .apk file? Using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Build > Build Bundle(s)/APK(s) > Build APK(s) from the toolbar menu.
APK file in the following path within your project folder

> app/build/outputs/apk/debug

İf you want to generate a signed APK file, open the Build menu from the toolbar and select Generate Signed Bundle/APK. In next screen you can check APK radio button.

Next step you’ll be asked about your Key store path, Key store password, Key alias, and the Key password
To do so, select Create new. You will find it underneath the input field where you enter the key store path. In the new window, enter the path for your new key store, and then enter a password to protect it.

Then next screen you can choose debug or release and select V2 (Full APK Signature) and click Finish.

You will find apk in your project folder in the

> app/release

Comment: how should I share that .apk file with others? so that they also can install & use my app?

Answer (score 0):

To build apk you need to type the command ./gradlew assemble in android studio terminal.  This command will create an APK which will be located at {project_path}/{your_module}/build/outputs/apk/